# Nativescript TextField into ListView not showing keyboard

Tags: textfield, nativescript

i have a Listview that is dynamically populated with TextFields (the ListView is binded to an observable object).

My problem is that the TextField is not showing the keyboard (Android) when receiving focus. A fixed TextField outside my ListView works regularly instead, and the device keyboard is shown.

This problem seems not to be happening on iOS.

I am using nativescript vanilla js (not angular, not Typescript).

Someone ha any suggestion to solve this problem ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

@Demetrio it would be great if you provide code snippets of the problematic code so others can reproduce your case ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

I have a test application demonstrating a list-view with TextView for its items and it works as expected for Android and for iOS. [The sample application here](https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Issues-2017/tree/master/stackoverflow/textViewList). Keep in mind that the project is created with NativeScript 3.0.0.